# Error When Running pip install pymssql

Tags: python, visual-studio, command-line

I am trying to install the pymssql module in the Command Prompt for VS 2017 Command line and when I type

```
pip install pymssql
```

I get this error

> `cl: error: no such option: -I`

Here is the more defined error code:

> cl: error: no such option: -I
>       error: command 'C:\Users\blake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\cl.exe'
>   failed with exit status 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, please follow the instructions on

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pymssql/step-1-configure-development-environment-for-pymssql-python-development?view=sql-server-2017

i. e.: Download the wheel-file, place it in the same folder where the python.exe is, move to that folder and run

pip install pymssql-2.1.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl